# There exists rational number $a_n$, $(x^2+\frac{1}{2}x+1)\mid(x^{2n}+a_nx^n+1)$

Tags: polynomials

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that there exists a rational number $a_n$ for which $$(x^2+\frac{1}{2}x+1)\mid(x^{2n}+a_nx^n+1)$$

My attempt :

I try $n=2$,

$(x^2+\frac{1}{2}x+1)(x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+1)=x^4+\frac{7}{4}x^2+1$

$a_2 = \frac{7}{4}$

Comment: Can you imagine there are two votes to close the question as "off topic"?! I quote what is certainly not off-topic, from the Help Center: "Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems, Mathematical problems such as one might come across in a course or textbook, Solving mathematical puzzles."

Comment: I don't understand why this is off topic.

Comment: It isn't, of course. Just some people at this site are very, very sick, and often forget to take their meds. They can vote to close only with a reputation of 3000 or more, so they know enough math to realize that this is _not_ off-topic. They're just misusing the power of their reputation, the poor bastards. Don't take it personally.

Comment: @Professor Vector. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We define $$p_n(x)=x^{2n}+a_n\,x^n+1,$$ so we have to prove
$$\left.x^2+\frac12\,x+1\right|p_n(x).$$
This is clearly true for $n=1$ with $a_1=1/2$, and it was shown for $n=2$ with $a_2=7/4$. Induction step: we assume it's true for $n=k-1$ and $n=k$.  Then, as can be seen by expanding the products,
$$p_{k+1}(x)=(x^{2k}+1)\left(x^2+\frac12\,x+1\right)-\frac12\,x\,p_k(x)-x^2\,p_{k-1}(x),$$ if only $$a_{k+1}=-\frac12\,a_k-a_{k-1},$$ so $$\left.x^2+\frac12\,x+1\right|p_{k+1}(x).$$

Comment: Since $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$, so $a_n \in \mathbb{Q}, \;\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thank you very much, Professor Vector.

Answer (score 3):

**just an idea**

The roots of the left polynom are

$$x_1=\frac{-1+i\sqrt {15} }{4}=e^{it}$$
$$x_2=\frac {-1-i\sqrt {15} }{4}=e^{-it} $$

they are also roots of the right one

$$e^{2int}+a_ne^{int}+1=0$$
$$e^{-2int}+a_ne^{-int}+1=0$$

thus
$$a_n=-\frac {\sin (2nt)}{\sin (nt)} $$

$$=-2\cos (nt) $$

For example,
$$a_2=-2\cos (2t)=2 (1-2\cos^2 (t)) $$
$$=2-4\frac {1}{16}=\frac {7}{4} $$

Comment: Correct, and since $\cos t=(e^{it}+e^{-it})/2=-1/4,$ you have the explicit expression $a_n=-2 T_n(-1/4),$ where $T_n$ are the Chebyshev polynomials of first kind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks a lot Professor. I did not think about Chebyshev.

Comment: Thank you, Salahamam_Fatima and ProfessorVector. Can this problem be solved using knowledge at high school level ?

Comment: @carat I'll give it a try.

Comment: Nice way of thinking about it! +1s to all in this thread.